# How to put drawable above radio button programmatically generated

Tags: android

I retrieve a quiz from a webservice and i want to render it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXrK5.png),

I'm trying to use RadioButtons programmatically generated.

I have image and text quiz, I use `rg.setOrientation();` to display quiz horizontaly / verticaly depends on the quizz type.

I tried to add image using **Drawable** but I can not put the RadioButton centered under the image. I'm only able to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DHel.png).
I can not center the text either

There is the code I wrote.

```
            final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        final int[] try_answer = {NUMBER_OF_TRY_MAX};


        if (question.getImage()) {

            if (!isTablet) {
                rg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            } else {
                rg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            }
                 rg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

            for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
                Answer answer = answers.get(i);
                RadioButton button = new RadioButton(getContext());


                db.open();
                Image img = db.getImageWithURL(answer.getPicture());
                db.close();
                String localName = img.getImage();
                String file = path + localName;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);


                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 300, true));


                d.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);
                button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,d,null,null);
                button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                button.setTag(answer.right_answer);
                button.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                button.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

                button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
                int[][] states = new int[][]{
                        new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
                        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
                        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
                        new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_checked}, // checked
                        new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
                };

                int[] colors = new int[]{
                        Color.WHITE,
                        Color.GRAY,
                        Color.WHITE,
                        Color.BLUE,
                        Color.BLUE
                };
                ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
                button.setButtonTintList(myList);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (try_answer[0] > 0) {

                            if ((Boolean) v.getTag()) {
                                displayRightAnswerImage(rg);
                                question.setAnswered(true);
                                checkIfAllQuestionsAnswered();
                            } else {
                                try_answer[0]--;

                                if (try_answer[0] == 0) {
                                    displayRightAnswerImage(rg);
                                    question.setAnswered(true);
                                    checkIfAllQuestionsAnswered();

                                } else {
                                    int selected = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                                    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)  v.findViewById(selected);
                                    Drawable[] drawables = rb.getCompoundDrawables();
                                    Drawable draw = drawables[1];
                                    draw.setAlpha(125);


                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "il reste " + try_answer[0] + " essais", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });

               rg.addView(button);

            }

        } else {
            rg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
                Answer answer = answers.get(i);
                final RadioButton button = new RadioButton(getContext());
                rg.addView(button);
                button.setText(answer.getTitle());
                button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                button.setTag(answer.right_answer);
                button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (try_answer[0] > 0) {
                            if ((Boolean) v.getTag()) {
                                displayRightAnswer(rg);
                                question.setAnswered(true);
                                checkIfAllQuestionsAnswered();

                            } else {
                                try_answer[0]--;

                                if (try_answer[0] == 0) {
                                    displayRightAnswer(rg);
                                    question.setAnswered(true);
                                    checkIfAllQuestionsAnswered();
                                } else {

                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "il reste " + try_answer[0] + " essais", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        }

    return v;
```

How can I get to make the display look similar to the first screen.

Is it possible or should I use another component than radiobutton to render it properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Relativelayout.LayoutParams object and add rules to it. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: I try it, but how can I add rules between my radio button & drawable?
I am not able to target the drawable

Comment: You don't target drawable, you point to the widget (like imageview) having that drawable.

Comment: I tried your method, but I can not make it work. I use `button.setRotation(-90)` & a Matrix to rotate the image to 90. But the radioButton is not correctly centered & text question neither.